# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied when using S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, pipenv

I'm following an online Udemy course ([Writing production-ready ETL pipelines in Python / Pandas | Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/writing-production-ready-etl-pipelines-in-python-pandas/)). I'm trying to connect AWS using CLI and accessing the dataset.

However I get the error:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

I created an IAM user with a standard policy `AmazonS3FullAccess`, so I think it should give all access to all resources. I don't understand why I'm still getting the error?

my code for this is:

```
aws s3 ls deutsche-boerse-xetra-pds/2021-04-21 --recursive --no-sign-request
```

AmazonS3FullAccess standard policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I expected to get an list of all the files as per specified s3 location and date
(`aws s3 ls deutsche-boerse-xetra-pds/2021-04-21`).

Comment: Remove the --no-sign-request argument. This is used to not sign requests. Thus Credentials will not be loaded if this argument is provided. It's usually used to access public buckets.

Comment: According to https://registry.opendata.aws/deutsche-boerse-pds/ this bucket is intended to be publicly accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This don't seems to be an issue from your side, but from the data owner. You may want to reach directly the owner data reporting the permission error:

https://registry.opendata.aws/deutsche-boerse-pds/

Comment: Thanks everyone, based on your feedback I got in touch with the course coordinator.  The data is indeed not available anymore but a work around has been provided.

Comment: please what is the workaround, as I am also trying to access the data using the same command for a similar project

Comment: @lingyaulee please can you provide the workaround